# Delete Foreign Keys

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have DB tables stored in XML format that have a FK based on two columns (Table2 has FK to Table1 based on ID and TYPE).

```
    Table1.xml
    <Table>
       <Row>
          <ID>1</ID>
          <TYPE>A</TYPE>
          <CONFIG>Y</CONFIG>
          ...
       </Row>
       <Row>
          <ID>2</ID>
          <TYPE>A</TYPE>
          <CONFIG>Z</CONFIG>
          ...
       </Row>
       <Row>
          <ID>1</ID>
          <TYPE>B</TYPE>
          <CONFIG>X</CONFIG>
          ...
       </Row>
       <Row>
          <ID>3</ID>
          <TYPE>A</TYPE>
          <CONFIG>Z</CONFIG>
          ...
       </Row>
    </Table>

    Table2.xml
    <Table>
       <Row>
          <ID>1</ID>
          <TYPE>A</TYPE>
          ...
       </Row>
       <Row>
          <ID>2</ID>
          <TYPE>A</TYPE>
          ...
       </Row>
       <Row>
          <ID>1</ID>
          <TYPE>B</TYPE>
          ...
       </Row>
       <Row>
          <ID>3</ID>
          <TYPE>A</TYPE>
          ...
       </Row>
    </Table>
```

I will have two XSLT files to delete rows in each XML file.  Table2 will be processed first.  I want to delete the row in Table2 where when joined with Table1 CONFIG=Z (ie, delete rows where (ID=2 and Type=A) and (ID=3 and Type=A), but I need to figure this out only knowing I want to delete records where CONFIG=Z).  Table1 will then be processed to delete rows where CONFIG=Z, which I was able to figure out.

I think the XSLT that will be applied to Table2 needs to read in Table1 XML (xsl:variable name="table1Rows" select="document('Table1.xml')/Table/Row"/>).  After that I'm lost on how to delete rows in Table2 where CONFIG=Z.  I've tried several things based on examples I saw, but couldn't get anything to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 define a key and cross-reference the elements, then simply do an identity transformation to copy nodes plus a template that suppresses the copying for those `Row` elements where the key function call finds a Row in the other document with the CONFIG being `Z`:

```
<xsl:variable name="table1" select="doc('Table1.xml')"/>

<xsl:key name="r-by-id-and-type" match="Table/Row" use="concat(ID, '|', TYPE)"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row[key('r-by-id-and-type', concat(ID, '|', TYPE), $table1)/CONFIG = 'Z']"/>
```

[edit] For completeness, I tested the following complete sample with both Saxon 9.4 as well as AltovaXML successfully:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:variable name="table1" select="doc('table1.xml')"/>

<xsl:key name="r-by-id-and-type" match="Table/Row" use="concat(ID, '|', TYPE)"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row[key('r-by-id-and-type', concat(ID, '|', TYPE), $table1)/CONFIG = 'Z']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On request in comment I also add an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:variable name="table1" select="document('test2012100102.xml')"/>

<xsl:key name="r-by-id-and-type" match="Table/Row" use="concat(ID, '|', TYPE)"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row">
  <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$table1">
    <xsl:if test="not(key('r-by-id-and-type', concat($this/ID, '|', $this/TYPE))/CONFIG = 'Z')">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$this"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XMLSpy is giving an error: Variables may not be used within this expression: Row[key('...', concat(...), --> $table1 <--)...

Comment: Ryan, you said you use XSLT 2.0, that expression is allowed in XSLT 2.0 (but not in 1.0 I think). So make sure you use an XSLT 2.0 processor. I tried a complete stylesheet with both Saxon 9.4 and AltovaXML and they run the code as intended.

Comment: Sorry - I'm new to XSLT.  I found out how to change the processor in XMLSpy and it worked.  If it's not too difficult, will you provide a solution for XSLT 1.0 for future reference?  Appreciate it.

Comment: I will add an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet, as there is no `key` function in XSLT 1.0 that takes the context document as the third parameter and as variables are not allowed in XSLT 1.0 match patterns you have to put some logic and context node change into the template `match="Row"`.

Comment: Thanks.. that works for me in XSLT 1.0, which I found out is the version I need to use on the target system.  Yesterday I had come up with a "beginner" solution, which seems to run faster than the one provided above, but is not as pretty.  I will post it as another answer.

Comment: I have a question about the use of "ID, '|', TYPE".  What does the pipe symbol do in this case.  I know the transform works, but the way I read it in my mind is "ID or TYPE" matches instead of "ID and TYPE" match.

Comment: Your description suggested you want to cross reference based on ID and TYPE values, as the key needs to be a single value the expression `concat(ID, '|', TYPE)` simply concatenates the two values into one string value, using a pipe character `|` as a separator character between ID and TYPE. For that approach you could use any character that is ensured to not occur in ID or TYPE. I chose '|' but of course if that character can occur in ID or TYPE choose another one. A separator character is helpful to ensure that e.g. ID as `1` and TYPE as `A1` are distinguished from `1A` as ID and `1` as TYPE.

Answer (score 0):

Martin's solution is correct, given the original question and should be accepted.

In reference to the OP's request for an additional XSLT 1.0 solution, here is a polyglot. This  style-sheet, a minor variation of Martin's solution, works on XSLT 2.0 processors and probably most XSLT 1.0 processors.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:variable name="table1" select="doc('table1.xml')"/>

<xsl:key name="r-by-id-and-type" match="Table/Row" use="concat(ID, '|', TYPE)"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="ident">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template
  match="Row"
  use-when="number(system-property('xsl:version')) &lt; 2" priority="2">
    <xsl:variable name="row" select="." />
    <xsl:variable name="id-type" select="concat(ID, '|', TYPE)" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$table1">
      <xsl:if test="not( key('r-by-id-and-type', $id-type))">
        <xsl:for-each select="$row">
          <xsl:call-template name="ident" />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:if> 
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template
  match="Row"
  use-when="number(system-property('xsl:version')) &gt;= 2" priority="1">
    <xsl:if test="not( key('r-by-id-and-type', concat(ID, '|', TYPE), $table1))">
      <xsl:call-template name="ident" />
    </xsl:if> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Caveat

This style-sheet was not tested.

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided by Martin work and are probably the best solutions possible.  For XSLT 1.0 I had come up with the following that seems to run faster, but is not as elegant. For this solution I knew that the only possible TYPE for CONFIG=Z is 'A'. (Note there could be a typo below since I'm running the XSLT on another machine and retyped it here with the mock column names/values.)

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> 
         <xsl:variable name="table1_Z_rows" select="document('table1.xml')/Table/Row[CONFIG='Z']"/>
             <xsl:template match="Row">
                  <xsl:choose>
                       <xsl:when test="TYPE != 'A'">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                       </xsl:when>
                       <xsl:otherwise>
                           <xsl:if test="not(ID = $table1_Z_rows/ID)">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                           </xsl:if>
                       </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
             </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```